# Shorthand MAC addresses

Tags: networking, mac-address

If I have a MAC represented as:

```
0:b:23:26:32:52
```

is that the same as:

```
00:0b:23:26:32:52
```

or:

```
00:bb:23:26:32:52
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would add the leading zeros, not repeat single characters (so `00:0b:23:26:32:52`, yes).

Chances are that the application in question just didn't format its output correctly with the leading zeros.

```
irb(main):003:0> sprintf '%X', 11
=> "B"
irb(main):004:0> sprintf '%02X', 11
=> "0B"
```

If you wanted to (somewhat) verify this, you could use a MAC lookup tool to check the manufacturer of the device.

According to [MAC_Find](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/), the `00:0b:23` prefix belongs to "Siemens Subscriber Network", while the other one is unknown.  That's not 100% proof of anything, but if you know the device is a Siemens device, that would be enough verification for most cases.